# Answer verification for Binomial Distribution problem

Tags: probability

**Question:**

> You buy a certain type of lottery ticket once a week for 4 weeks.  What's the probability you win a cash prize exactly twice?

**My attempt:**

P(Success) = $1/4 $

P(Not Successful) =$ 3/4$

$$4 \ _nC^r \ 2 \times \bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)^2 \times \bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^2 = 0.2109375$$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: In R statistical software, the PDF of binomial is `dbinom`. With appropriate parameters it becomes: `dbinom(2, 4, 1/4)`, which returns  0.2109375. So Yes, correct. //  Here is how you can make ${4 \choose 2}$ in MathJax: `${4 \choose 2}$`

Comment: @BruceET Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is indeed correct. In order to check your calculation I highly recommend Wolfram Alpha :

```
Probability that X=2 if X has a binomial distribution with n=4 and p=.25
```

(0.210937).

Link : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=probability+that+X%3D2+if+X+has+a+binomial+distribution+with+n%3D4+and+p%3D.25

Answer (score 2):

Let $X\sim \text{Binom}\left(n=4,p=\frac{1}{4}\right)$, a random variable having a binomial distribution.

Then its probability mass function is 
$$
p(x) = b(x;n,p)= b(x;4,0.25) = 
\begin{cases} 
\displaystyle{\binom{4}{x}}(0.25)^x (0.75)^{4-x} &\mbox{ if } x = 0,1,2,3, 4, \\  
\hspace{16mm}0 &\mbox{ otherwise}. 
\end{cases}
$$
Then the probability of winning a cash prize exactly twice is 
$$
P(X=2)= p(2) = \displaystyle{\binom{4}{2}}(0.25)^2 (0.75)^{4-2} \approx 0.210938. 
$$